# Logging into sandbox subdomain WP

Tags: wp-admin, login, subdomains

I have recently set up a subdomain to do wordpress testing on. I installed a new wordpress instance at `sandbox.example.com`. I have a main one set up at example.com. When I try to log into my new instance, I am having issues. I go to `sandbox.example.com/wp-login.php` but that page will only take my main site's login credentials, and it redirects me to my main site. How can I log into my sandbox wordpress instance?

Comment: That should not happen with a fresh installation of WordPress on the subdomain. Did you copy anything at all across from the `example.com` instance?

Comment: I copied the database, but added a new table for my second site.